# Sum of part of a list that increases in length

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, summation

I have a list of numbers whose length increases by 1 for every iteration of a loop. I need to take the sum of the last 5 elements of the list, and if the list's length is smaller than 1 I need to have the total sum of the existing elements (for length of 1 to 4). I have found the following crude solution, where the "ted" step is an If function.

```
bill := {}
Do[{bill = Append[bill, 1],
  ted = If[Length[bill] < 5, Total[bill], Total[Take[bill, -5]]]},
 {i, 1, 10}]
```

The numbers in the list don't matter, feel free to use distribution drawings etc.

I was looking for a faster, more elegant way to perform the same procedure. Any ideas? And thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListCorrelate[ConstantArray[1, 5], Range[10], {5}, 0]
```

> {1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40}

This moves the "kernel" `{1,1,1,1,1}` along the list `Join[ConstantArray[0, 4], Range[10]]]` and forms `Dot` products. It should be equivalent to

```
ListCorrelate[ConstantArray[1, 5], Join[ConstantArray[0, 4], Range[10]]]
```

which might be a bit easier to understand.

If you need only the last value, then

```
Total[list[[Max[1, Length[list] + 1 - 5] ;;]]]
```

should do.

If you need that for many lists, you can try to use `Compile`:

```
data = Range /@ RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 100000];
a = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
      Total[list[[Max[1, Length[list] + 1 - 5] ;; -1]]],
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
      ][data]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.041

But beware that `CompiledFunctions` don't like empty lists. So you have to assure that `data` does not contain any lists of length `0`. If you want to sum not only integers but real numbers, you should change `{list, _Integer, 1}` within `Compile` to `{list, _Real, 1}`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that does indeed what I had in mind with one crucial difference. In each iteration of my loop, I will need only the last result, e.g. when the list has a length of 10 I would need only 40 as output, not the other 9 elements or the entire list. I can use Part or something else, of course, but for efficiency reasons is there a way to avoid calculating the previous sums every time (i.e. in every i of the loop in my question?)

Comment: I had used that Total function and it is as efficient as the If function I had used (both take 7 seconds for 50k repetitions). Still, it is a compact solution. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome!